# K&R style function definition problem

Tags: c, function-declaration

The following code works:

```
int main()
{
   void foo(int);
   foo(3);
   return 0;
}
void foo(a) int a;
{
   printf("In foo\n");
}
```

but this one does not:

```
int main()
{
   void foo(float);
   foo(3.24);
   return 0;
}
void foo(a) float a;
{
   printf("In foo\n");
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you mean by works? Does it compile or not? Does it run or not? What's the problem?

Comment: Because the 2nd example hasn't been valid syntax for longer than either of us has been alive?

Comment: @Nick: No, it doesnt compile. This is the error: conflicting types for ‘foo’.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Actually, kind of an interesting question.

This has to do with the evolution of the C language and the way it arranges to be backwards-compatible to the older flavors.

In both cases, you have a K&R-era definition for `foo()`, but a C99 declaration (with prototype) earlier.

But in the first case, the default parameter of `int` actually is the parameter, so the function call is compatible.

In the second case, though, the K&R definition brings in the standard argument promotions rule from the K&R era and the type of the parameter is really `double`.

But, you used a modern prototype at the call site, making it a `float`.  So the code at the call site might have pushed a real `float`, which is in any case a distinct type from `double`.

If all of the references to `foo()` were K&R style, I believe the most you would get would be a warning, which is what compilers would have done back then, and the compiler must act like that to compile the legacy code. It would even have been a type-safe call because the floats would all be promoted to double, at least for the procedure call interface. (Not necessarily for the internal function code.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I should have said that the rules that include promoting float arguments to doubles are called *the default argument promotions*. Also, we usually refer to any version of ANSI C as C99, because the C99 standard replaced the C89 one. But since we were specifically discussing language evolution, perhaps I should have noted that the prototype expressions originated with C89.

Comment: Strictly speaking, ANSI C has been obsolete since 1990, since ANSI C = C89. The first ISO C standard is C90. Though of course, ANSI C and C90 are identical in function, and only different in chapter enumeration and various other cosmetics.

Comment: Sure, I was trying to refer to revisions with prototypes, which began with ANSI C, but I guess "ISO C" would have been a better choice.

Comment: the question is good but I never will write something like this, always need a prototype in the header